# AWS S3 put object is taking more time to upload file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am working on uploading image file in AWS S3 bucket by using putObject method in lambda. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property

But putObject is taking more than 20 second to upload 5 MB image file and 
**all of my resources are hosted in same region** so implementing accelerate endpoint is also not making any difference.

http://s3-accelerate-speedtest.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/en/accelerate-speed-comparsion.html?region=REGION-NAME&origBucketName=BUCKET-NAME

Is this the expected time to upload file or is there any other way to accelerate the uploading time ?

Comment: The performance of Accelerated Transfer is depends on your location. But for me, it is not faster at all, I prefer handling all traffic using proxy

Comment: Does the file successfully upload, or does your Lambda time out? Is your Lambda running inside or outside a VPC? What is the actual code that you're using to do the upload?

Comment: @kdgregory file is uploading successfully, but the issue is it is taking more than 20 second to upload 5MB file, I have no idea, is this expected time taken by S3 or we can accelerate ... !!

Comment: No, this is not expected time. If you're uploading to an S3 bucket in the same region, 5 MB should take a fraction of a second. How are you measuring the time?

Comment: @kdgregory we created VPC endpoint for S3 service and now there is some improvement in performance while uploading file. Thank's man..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We created VPC endpoint for S3 service and now there is some good improvement in performance while uploading file.